# Url rewrite multiple folders

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Im trying to find if this is possible. I have no code to show (yet) as I'm not sure where to start.

I am trying to create a website that has a couple of folders;

Root
/SiteName
../FolderA
../FolderB
and so on...

As an example on my localhost to preview a html file in FolderA the browser path would be:

http://localhost/Sitename/FolderA/Afile.html

What I'd love to do is have the ability to type

http://localhost/Sitename

and it starts opens http://localhost/Sitename/FolderA/Afile.html (which would be my login page)

Is this possible ?

Of course from there the other pages and modules could be called, but it would be nice to hide those pathes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to below rule:

```
<rule name="test3" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="Afile.html" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/Sitename/FolderA/Afile.html$" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
```

[image]